# Swift: Creating an Array of Users from Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I just started programming with `Swift` so to help me learn the language better, I am creating an application similar to `Tinder` but for making friends. I have the registration process all done and now I am working on getting the other users to show up as cards that the user will swipe through. To do this, I am wanting to somehow create an array of eligible users so I can access each users data but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Don't hesitate to ask if you need further clarification. All help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CardsVC: UIViewController {
    var membersInSchool = [User]()
    var cardCount = 0
    //@IBOutlet weak var cardView: CardView!
    @IBOutlet weak var potentialMatchImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var potentialMatchName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var potentialMatchGrade: UILabel!

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchPotentialMatches()
        //I want to implement completion handler here so setUpCard() only runs after fetchPotentialMatches() finishes
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
            self.setUpCard()
        })
    }

    @IBAction func skip(_ sender: Any) {
        setUpCard()
    }

    @IBAction func like(_ sender: Any) {
        setUpCard()
    }


    func fetchPotentialMatches(){
        //Get the current user's information
        let userRef = ref.child("users").child(uid!)
        userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)
            print(user.highSchool!)
            print(user.matchPreference!)
            let currentUserSchool = user.highSchool!
            let currentUserMatch = user.matchPreference!

//Get all the users uid's in the current user's school
ref.child("schools").child(currentUserSchool).child("members").observe(.value , with: { (snapshot) in
                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        let child = child as? DataSnapshot
                        if let otherUsers = child?.key {
//Get the information about each user in this school
                            ref.child("users").child(otherUsers).observe(.value, with: { (snap) in
                                let otherU = User(snapshot: snap)
                                //Check if user is not the current signed in user and the user matches the current user's match preference
                                if otherU.uid != uid! && otherU.gender == currentUserMatch {
                                    self.membersInSchool.append(otherU)
                                    print(otherU.firstName!)
                                    print(otherU.lastName!)
                                    let name = otherU.firstName! + " " + otherU.lastName!

                                }

                            })
                        }
                    }

                })

        }){(error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

//Set up the card
    func setUpCard(){
        print(membersInSchool)
                var potMatchName = membersInSchool[cardCount].firstName! + " " + membersInSchool[cardCount].lastName!
                potentialMatchName.text! = potMatchName
                var potMatchGrade = membersInSchool[cardCount].grade!
                potentialMatchGrade.text! = potMatchGrade
                self.cardCount += 1
    }
}
```

I am currently getting an out of range error when I try to access membersInSchool[1]. I figured this is because when I append each user, it doesn't create a new object in the array and instead adds the user to membersInSchool[0].

Here is the code for my User class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct User {

    var firstName : String!
    var lastName : String!
    var gender : String!
    var matchPreference : String!
    var photoURL : String!
    var highSchool : String!
    var grade : String!
    var uid : String!
    var ref : DatabaseReference?
    var key : String!

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        key = snapshot.key
        ref = snapshot.ref
        firstName = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["first name"] as! String
        lastName = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["last name"] as! String
        gender = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["gender"] as! String
        matchPreference = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["match preference"] as! String
        photoURL = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["pic"] as? String
        highSchool = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["School"] as! String
        grade = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["grade"] as! String
        uid = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["uid"] as! String
    }


}
```

Comment: You are calling `setupCard` long before `fetchPotentialMatches` has even begun fetching an users.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah I realized that and I am using the delay as a short-term fix. I still am trying to learn how to implement a completion handler so setUpCard only gets called after fetchPotentialMatches has finished.